# Creating new class objects dynamically via user input in C++

Tags: c++, class, user-input

I am new to C++. For a final project in an online class, I am writing a program that is essentially a virtual time card to track hours worked at a job. I apologize for any blatant flaws in my code, it is still a work in progress, and this class had me take on a lot of new concepts really fast.

I have a class called `Employee`, and in that class I have a function called `newEmployee()` that allows the user to register a new employee to be tracked by the program. Here is a piece of my header file:

```
class Employee {
private:
    std::string Name;
    double Pay;
    bool Admin;

public:
    Employee(std::string& name, double pay, bool admin);
    void getInput();
    void newEmployee();
    void getStatus();
    void clockIn();
    int clockOut();
    int timer();
    int exportTimeSheet();
```

And here is my implementation of the constructor:

```
Employee::Employee(std::string& name, double pay = 0.0, bool admin = false) {
    Name = name;
    Pay = pay;
    Admin = admin;
}
```

The issue I'm having is, I don't know how to dynamically create a new class object via user input. The `newEmployee()` function asks them for the name of the employee (`string`), how much they get paid (`double`), and if they are an admin (`boolean`).

I'm familiar with using the `new` and `delete` keywords to make dynamic variables at run time, but if the function is called multiple times by the user, how can I parse a user input string into the class constructor and dynamically make multiple new unique class objects?

Comment: `Employee* employee = new Employee{"John"};`

Comment: `void newEmployee();` is not an interface that makes it easy to return a new Employee. I guess it could modify an existing one but then its a bad naming.

Answer (score 2):

You need a container of Employee objects - I suggest a vector

```
std::vector<Employee> employees;

while (still getting input){
    string name = get from input;
    Employee emp(name,...);
    employees.push_back(emp);
}
```

Or better, use pointers (saves a lot of copying):

```
std::vector<Employee*> employees;

while (still getting input){
    string name = get from input;
    Employee *emp = new Employee(name,...);
    employees.push_back(emp);
}
```

The downside here is that you have to remember to free up all that memory you dynamically allocated.

So you can use a smart pointer instead:

```
using EmployeePtr = std::shared_ptr<Employee>;
std::vector<EmployeePtr> employees;

while (still getting input){
    string name = get from input;
    auto emp = std::make_shared<Employee>(name,...);
    employees.push_back(emp);
}
```

To get at the data, you use:

```
 employees[n].Name (#1)
 employees[n]->Name (#2 and #3)
```

Comment: If you're just worried about the copies, you could do `employees.emplace_back(name, ...);` instead of converting everything to shared pointers.

Comment: Ideally, if you do use smart pointers, you should prefer `unique_ptr` over `shared_ptr` whenever possible.  This example does not need sharing semantics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I proposed shared_ptrs for maximum flexibility, looking at the description in the question I suspect we are going to see a complicated graph of classes, shared_ptr will always work

Answer (score 1):

You say `newEmployee()` prompts for an employee's info.  But its return value is a `void`, so it can't return a new `Employee`.  Try something more like this instead:

```
class Employee {
    ...
    static Employee newEmployee();
    ...
};
```

```
Employee Employee::newEmployee() {
    std::string name;
    double pay;
    bool admin;

    // read in values as needed...

    return Employee(name, pay, admin);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Employee emp = Employee::newEmployee();
// use emp as needed...
```

Or, if you need to create the `Employee` object dynamically:

```
class Employee {
    ...
    static std::unique_ptr<Employee> newEmployee();
    ...
};
```

```
std::unique_ptr<Employee> Employee::newEmployee() {
    std::string name;
    double pay;
    bool admin;

    // read in values as needed...

    return std::make_unique<Employee>(name, pay, admin);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
auto emp = Employee::newEmployee();
// use emp as needed...
```